# TvP: How to counter Protoss double expand if you commited to 1rax expand yourself?

Tags: starcraft-2

Last time I play my TvP match-up 1rax-fast expand. If I see Protoss does 1gate expand I do 1 more CC. That worked well until I get higher in ranking.

Now I often see Protoss does double expand. If I committed to fast-expand myself I can't do a solid damage to him, and he win with a better macros/micro. Probably if I do 3rax expand, that would help, but what if I've started with FE?

Any suggestions or ideas for this case would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone expands early there are generally 3 options that you can go for.

**Match him expansion for expansion:** This will allow you to keep up economically with him and will give you a better chance at winning a macro game. This plans for the long run option of the game. If you don't go this route, as you mention they will probably win with better macro. With the proper use of mules you shouldn't fall behind to a protoss on 3 base, even with chrono boost being used. You should be able to keep up. Especially if you don't take gas and pump out nothing but marines for defense and scvs.

**Apply pressure:** This will require you to do something like dropping 5 or 6 more barracks and just go for a heavy heavy push that needs to do damage. Damage can be something as simple as knocking off one of the expansions or killing lots of workers or knocking out a key tech structure (Cybernetics core, robotics facility, robotics bay, star gate, etc.). This will push them back technologically and allow you to get your third base up or to keep applying pressure with your units. A +1 attack and stim timing push can do a lot of damage if executed at the right place on the map.

**Tech up quickly:** Going for something like cloaked banshees really quickly will punish him for expanding so quickly. Or even something as simple as 2 medivacs to go with a stim timing push will make your infantry army that much stronger. Or get seige tanks quickly and do a siege tank push on his 3rd, or even into his natural and up to his main. Quick expansions biggest weakness is low tech. So if you go for quicker technological upgrades then you have the tech advantage and can use that to win you the game.

Comment: +1 for the tech suggestion - day9 talks about exactly this in his latest daily http://blip.tv/day9tv/day-9-daily-444-white-ra-vs-bly-6084445 where you aim to recognise your edge and capitalise on it - if the opponent is ahead economically, tech to something he will struggle to deal with due to his lower tech.

Answer (score 0):

As he has 3 bases to defend you could add only 2 new rax (instead of 3) get 4 gas immediately after expansion starts mining, then fast tech to medivacs and drop him. While doing that you can expand yourself again.

Make sure you poke him constantly so he is forced to commit to static defense in all locations.

You can also try to 3 or 4 rax marrauder with the marines you have from the start. He will not have enough defense to secure everything, so you have a good chance to kick at least one expansion.

For this you need to add at least 2 gas once you start mining at your 2nd.

Pull back once you kick his expansion and start dropping if he tries to attack you.